# What do you call someone who hides files?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm writing a novel about a woman who hides files because she fears that other people may access information she wants to keep secret.

Mary Lou doesn't follow a precise method for hiding files in hard-disks, but she does so with excessive zeal.

So, as ever, I would like to know whether there is an adjective to describe Mary Lou.

After a bit of searching I found that [bibliotaph](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bibliotaph) means 'one that hides away or hoards books', but, alas, it seems that one can properly uses this word only in reference to books, not files.

So, I wonder, what do you call someone who hides away files?

Comment: I edited out a few grammar/style shortcomings, but I'm not sure exactly what you mean to imply by ***hoards*** files. People normally *hide* things because they don't want others to find them, but *hoarding* is more about building up a [usually, *excessive*] stockpile of something. Hoarding isn't necessarily a *secretive* activity. It's just that because the hoard usually contains more than the hoarder actually *needs*, and often contains something *other people need too*, it's likely to be done secretively to avoid opprobrium, jealousy, demands to share, etc.

Comment: A *data-hoarder*? *Data-deceptionist*? A *crypto-filo-facist*?

Answer (score 1):

Consider that fine word  *[obscurantist](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/obscurantist)* (“A practitioner of obscurantism; an obscurant”), where *[obscurantism](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/obscurantism#Noun)* has a sense “being deliberately obscure or vague”, and  *[obscurant](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/obscurant)* as an adjective means  “Acting or tending to confound, obfuscate, or obscure”, or as a noun,   “One who acts to confound or obfuscate; an obscurantist” or  “A person who seeks to prevent or hinder enquiry and the advancement of knowledge or wisdom; an agent of endarkenment”.  The latter phrase also suggest the term *endarkener*.

Note, by the way, that  “[security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity)” (a general term for keeping things secret by hiding them) often is denigrated as a security policy.

Answer (score 1):

You mean Mary Lou is a paranoid ***pack-rat***, or a ***magpie*** even?

*Definitions*

> - a person who accumulates things and hides them away for future use.
> - One who compulsively collects or hoards small objects.

Answer (score 0):

A chipmunk, they are notorious for hiding things and not always capable even to find them back. But, the things are well hidden!
A squirrel may work as well, you know, "squirreling things away"?